# Right(text;5) is not the same as a 5 character text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a match function that I could not get working. I boiled it down to the point that it can't find the appropriate match since the values are not the same, apparently.

I have the value 21337 in cell D59. In cell S59 I have the function: Right($d59;5), which displays 21337. However when I enter in a cell: =D59=S59 i get the return FALSE.

I use the Right() function because cells in column D contain concatenated values, where the last 5 values are of importance. For example D60 contains 21337 - 21448, where 21448 is the value I want to match.

Anyone has a clue on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no formatting you'll see that 21337 is right aligned - showing this is a number and treated as a number by Excel.
On the other hand `Right($d59;5)` will show the number left aligned, indicating that the returned value is being treated as text by Excel.

If you try `Right($d59;5)*1` Excel will implicitly convert the value back to a number (due to the calculation performed) and both values will be equal.

To be explicit about the conversion, as Brian has pointed out, use `VALUE(Right($d59;5))`.

Comment: Thank you. So simple yet so far away ;)

Comment: No probs.  I'll have to remember this post - took me over 5k rep for the first time. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook +1 for a good answer but wouldn't that be an implicit conversion? Explicitly, you could say `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1;5))`.

Comment: Good point @Brian.  I think I was rushing the answer (and probably bad habits).  I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Formula" > "Evaluate Formula", does it show the penultimate Evaluation as`21337="21337"`

The LEFT(..) function will convert the number to a string, and the string and the number will not equate.  Try either `=TEXT(D59,"#")=S59` or `=D59=N(Left(S59))` to convert in your comparison, or change the code in S59 to `=N(Right($D59,5))` to make S59 show a number

(The N(..) function converts a string to a number, returns 0 if Not A Number)